# Backend and DB with NextJS

Tags: next.js

I started to create my project with NextJs, but I have some issues with the Backend of next js.

As Next is mostly the frontend part, how can I set up backend for next js?

I am looking for some tutorials to install BE, also I am interested to investigate some hostings. As I know, I can setup BE with Azure, some Express etc.

I will be happy if you share some knowledge about it.

Thanks!

Comment: for hosting vercel comes with many great features supported out of the box for nextjs. and for backend I don't think if it really matters. any rest api, graphql, etc should do.

Comment: Yes, but I like to separate BE and FE really, so what should I do?

Comment: Just a personal suggestion: Ignore the fact that you can do backend inside nextjs and request you data from server just like you would normally do in any react application. [Thispage](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) from nextjs explains all forms of data fetching.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know I can get data for example, in getStaticProps from API. But what I am looking for, it's really BE functions, for example, how to authenticate users, how to retrieve data etc. Imagine I have /api/getUsers in next (middleware) and getUsers with backend code wich describes behavior of getUsers.

Comment: You can always fetch data on client side. Take a look at [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side).